# How to know if linq returned an object?

Tags: linq, entity-framework

for example.

I have a linq query to search a customer

```
var customer = from c in _repo
               where c.username == username
               select c;
```

How to tell if customer is found?

I've tried

```
if(customer)
```

But VS says can't implicitly convert type Models.Customer to bool

The model is generated by EF4.

Since used repository pattern.

The single method returns 
public TEntity Single(Expression> predicate)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're really trying to find a single customer, so use:

```
var customer = _repo.SingleOrDefault(c => c.username == username);
if (customer != null)
{
    ...
}
```

If there might be *multiple* customers with the same name, you should consider whether you want to find all of them, or whether you can just use the first one. If you can give more details about what you're trying to do, we can help more.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Enumerable.Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx):

```
if (customer.Any())
```